# Discord Giveaway bot always gives the bot as winner

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The bot should return that "no one entered" when no one enters the giveaway, but even if that's the case, it still says "@Dbot winner". Am I missing something in the code?

```js
    let msg = await message.channel.send(
      "**GIVEAWAY**",
      {
        embed: {
          title: `${(args.slice(2, args.length)).join(" ")}`,
          color: 3447003,
          description: `React with  to enter!\nTime to enter: ${args[0]}\nWinners: ${args[1]}`,
          footer: {
            text: `dbot 2021 © giveaway ends ${endTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`
          }
        }
      });
      await msg.react('')
      setTimeout(() => {
          msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.remove(msg.author.id)
          setTimeout(() => {
              let winner = msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache.random();
              if (msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache.size < 1) {
                msg.channel.send(`No one entered giveaway :sadge:`);
              }
              if (!msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache.size < 1) {
                console.log(winner);
                msg.channel.send(`${winner} is our winner! check 1`);
              }
          }, 3000);
      }, timerMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you first check if `users.cache.size` is less than 1, then `if (!msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache.size < 1)`.

`users.cache.size` will return a number and in JavaScript `!number` will return a boolean. Check the snippet below:

```js
const num0 = 0;
const num1 = 1;
const num2 = 2;

console.log(num0, !num0);
console.log(num1, !num1);
console.log(num2, !num2);
```

This means that with your second if statement, you're checking if `false` is less than `1`, which is true in JavaScript.

To fix this, you simply need to convert the second if to an else statement:

```js
if (msg.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache.size < 1) {
  msg.channel.send(`No one entered giveaway :sadge:`);
} else {
  console.log(winner);
  msg.channel.send(`${winner} is our winner! check 1`);
}
```

Comment: That solution gives me the same output.. "@dbot is our winner!:tada::tada::tada:"

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable the `MEMBERS` intent on the Discord Developer Console and add that intent to your `ClientOptions`.

Comment: How is this related to this question?

Comment: I misread the question and took it as "the bot always selects itself" which is what this would solve.